Why do I get this warning Argument of type '' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ label: string; value: string | undefined; }[]>'
I'm trying to pass the array of object to my state after performing a form.watch() but I get this warning.

Argument of type '({ label: string; value: string | undefined; } | { label: string; value: string | string[]; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ label: string; value: string | undefined; }[]>'.
Type '({ label: string; value: string | undefined; } | { label: string; value: string | string[]; })[]' is not assignable to type '{ label: string; value: string | undefined; }[]'.

After performing a form.watch() I put it in an array of object and I will pass it to the child prop, but I have this warning.
  const [dataFinalize, setDataFinalize] = useState<({ label: string; value: string | undefined })[]>([]); 


 const watch = form.watch([
        "title",
        "email",
        "fullName",
        "department",
        "dateOfEvent",
        "startingTime",
        "endingTime",
        "purpose",
        "doesHaveDryRun",
        "dryRunDate",
        "dryRunStart",
        "dryRunEnd",
        "doesHaveTCETAssitance",
        "tcetOtherAssitance",
        "meetingType",
        "meetingTypeServices",
        "meetingTypeServiceLink"
      ]);

      const previewResult = [
        {
          label: "Title: ",
          value: watch[0],
        },
        {
          label: "Email: ",
          value: watch[1],
        },
        {
          label: "Full Name: ",
          value: watch[2],
        },
        {
          label: "Department: ",
          value: watch[3],
        },
        {
          label: "Date of Event: ",
          value: watch[4],
        },
        {
          label: "Starting Time: ",
          value: watch[5],
        },
        {
          label: "Ending Time: ",
          value: watch[6],
        },
        {
          label: "Purpose: ",
          value: watch[7],
        },

        {
          label: "Dry Run: ",
          value: watch[8],
        },
        {
          label: "Dry Label Date: ",
          value: watch[9],
        },
        {
          label: "Dry Run Staring Time: ",
          value: watch[10] ? watch[10] : "None",
        },
        {
          label: "Dry Run Ending Time: ",
          value: watch[11] ? watch[11] : "None",
        },
        {
          label: "Tech Assitance: ",
          value: watch[12],
        },
        {
          label: "Tech Assistance Name: ",
          value: watch[13] ? watch[13] : "None",
        },
        {
          label: "Meeting Type: ",
          value: watch[14],
        },
        {
          label: "Meeting Type Services: ",
          value: watch[15],
        },
        {
          label: "Livestream Link",
          value: watch[15] ? watch[15] : "None",
        }
      ];

    setDataFinalize(previewResult)


One of elements in watch array is an array itself (instead of string/undefined) which screws the type of previewResult.
You need to either make sure you use only string/undefined as value or update type used in useState

@OlegWock, thank you, is there anyway I can set it to any?
